# A question in Ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the modified equation when the implicit Euler method is applied to $y'= f(y)$. If $f(y)=λy$, where $λ$ is negative. what is the effect on the amplication factor?

$y ' = λ y$

$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = λ y$

$\Rightarrow dy / y = λ dx $

$\Rightarrow \ln y = λx + C$

$\Rightarrow y = Ae^{\lambda x}$,

where the constant factor does not depend on $\lambda$.

This is what I have done so far. Can anyone help me what to do next to answer the question?

Comment: what is the amplification factor? if you mean $\lambda$, it is the rate at which the solution decays to zero with respect to increase of x. i.e. $\lambda=\frac{-1}{x_{c}}$ where $x_{c}$ is a characteristic measure of x, then the smaller that value, i.e. large $\lambda$, then the solution will tend to zero quicker. Also you can look at the half-life of the solution when $y=\frac{A}{2}$ as this is a measure of rate of dampening. I hope this rather long comment helps.

Answer (score 2):

The implicit Euler scheme is given by:

$$y_{n+1} = y_n + h f(y_{n+1}, t_{n+1})$$

For $f(y)=\lambda~y$, we have:

$$y_{n+1} = y_n + h f(y_{n+1}, t_{n+1}) = y_n + h~\lambda~y_{n+1}$$

Solving this for $y_{n+1}$ (in general, this is not possible), we arrive at:

$$\tag 1 y_{n+1} = \dfrac{y_n}{1 - h ~\lambda}$$

From $(1)$, we can see that if $|1 - h ~ \lambda| \ge 1$, the solution is decaying (stable). Compare this to the actual solution of $y(x) = c e^{\lambda~x}$.

If we have $\lambda$ being negative, we would have:

$$\tag 2 y_{n+1} = \dfrac{y_n}{1 + h ~\lambda}$$

Compare this to the actual solution of $y(x) = c e^{-\lambda~x}$. What conclusion can you draw?

I would recommend actually generating numerical data using this scheme and seeing what is going on since we have the closed form solution to compare against.

Try it for $\lambda = \pm 1$ and see what happens to stability.

Comment: is it modified euler scheme same as the euler scheme given by: y_(n+1)=  y_n +hf(y_n+1 , t_n+1 )

Comment: how did you get actual solution y(x) = ce^(λt)  and another actual solution  y(x) = ce^(-λt)

Comment: i got my exact solution y(x)= Ae^(λt), BUT YOU HAVE GOT y(x)=ce^(λt) in terms of t, is your actual solution same as mine?

Comment: what about e^(λt)? is e^(λt) same as e^(λx)